# lambda Java 8, how to map a list that is a filed of the result of filter operation

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a catalog-like object hierarchy where every object has a name field.

```
class A {
    List<A> list;
    String name;
}

A{A{A{A...}AA},A{AAA},A{AAA}} // the depth is finite (~4)
```

I would like to provide a set of methods that return a list of child names (a a.getName()) of any parent element for a given name.
So for level 1 I have

```
a.getAs().stream().map(a1 -> a1.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Level 2 I have already troubles with:

```
a1.getAs().stream().filter(a2 -> a2.getName() == name)
```

now I want to access the As and map them to their names but I don't know how

EDIT:
I have just realized that from the third level on it wouldn't be possible to find the list with just providing a single name. I would need a name for each level to be able to navigate to the node where the child list could be collected.
On one hand I could keep all the objects in one Set and access them with an id. They would still have references to each other. On the other hand by not knowing the root element I couldn't get the structure right.

I think I have to rethink the problem.

Comment: Does a `getAs` return a `List<A>`? and why do you want to do that with Stream API?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve with the filter in your last statement?

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko: yes, it does. The Stream API is more efficient and brings a better readability plus it can be executed in parallel.

Comment: ... in some cases

Comment: @ErnestKiwele given a String 'name' I filter out an entry from a list that matches it, then I want to access the list within the distinct filtered object to map the list elements to their names only. I always start from root and dive all the way down to the level I am interested in

Comment: I of course could achieve it with multi level for statements but what are the Streams for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
public static List<String> getChildNames(A node, String... path) {
    Stream<A> s = node.getAs().stream();
    for(String name: path)
        s = s.filter(a -> a.getName().equals(name)).flatMap(a -> a.getAs().stream());
    return s.map(A::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

but if the names beneath an `A` node are unique, you should consider maintaining a `Map<String,A>`, mapping from child name to actual child, instead of a `List<A>`. That would make traversing a path via unique name/ID as simple as `node.get(name1).get(name2)`. The logic of the method above would still be useful if you incorporate pattern matching, which doesn’t need to have a unique result.

```
public static List<String> getChildNames(A node, String... pathPatterns) {
    Stream<A> s = node.getAs().stream();
    for(String namePattern: pathPatterns) {
        Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(namePattern);
        s = s.filter( a -> compiledPattern.matcher(a.getName()).find())
             .flatMap(a -> a.getAs().stream());
    }
    return s.map(A::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: [`Pattern.asPredicate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#asPredicate--) :-)

Comment: @Didier L: unfortunately not so much helpful here, as we still have to combine it with `getName()`. I really wish, `Predicate` had a method to compose it with a `Function`…  In our code base, we have such a utility method, but examples on SO should work self-contained.

Comment: the uniques of the names can only be guaranteed within the same list. The code above is tested and is a valid solution to the initial requirement. Although the flatMap chaining approach was partially mentioned by @Andrew Tobilko . I am not sure who's answer am I supposed to accept?

Comment: “within the same list” exactly what I meant with “beneath an `A` node”. That implies that you can replace the list with a map, as each `A` instance will have its own map. Regarding which answer to accept, it’s entirely your choice. See [help/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer): “*Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally*”.

Answer (score 2):

It works only for one level of the hierarchy:

```
public List<A> getSubcategoriesByParentName(A category, String name) {
    return category.getSubcategories()
                   .stream()
                   .filter(subcategory -> subcategory.getName().equals(name))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

To achieve the next level, you could use a `flatMap`:

```
category.getSubcategories().stream()
        .flatMap(s -> s.getSubcategories().stream())
        .filter(s -> s.getName().equals(name))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As you can see, there is a need of recursion, it is not a work for Stream API.

Of course, being aware of the depth, we could access to all levels (by using a `flatMap(s -> s.getSubcategories().stream())` several times), but it will look ugly.

Comment: Guess you could add more "levels of hierarchy" by putting the `flatmap` and `filter` part in a loop and collecting only at the very end.

Comment: Since the depth is said to be finite (at most 4), there shouldn’t be any problem chaining up to four `flatMap` steps without any recursion.